# Insert a character 4 chars before end of string in BASH

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash, sed

Is there a way to insert a colon 4 chars before the end of a string? For example, I have 0x2aab3f439000 and I need 0x2aab3f43:9000

Thanks

Comment: if it'd be a file, then you can use sed but if it's just a string variable, then you can easily try: a=0x2aab3f439000; suffix=":9000"; a=${a}${suffix}; echo $a; #this assume you know value of suffix variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using sed you can do:

```
s='0x2aab3f439000'
sed 's/.\{4\}$/:&/' <<< "$s"
0x2aab3f43:9000
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ s=0x2aab3f439000
$ echo "${s:0:(${#s}-4)}:${s:(-4)}"
0x2aab3f43:9000
```

Alternative (from glenn jackman):

```
echo "${s%????}:${s: -4}"
```

Comment: Using your first example worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`a=0x2aab3f439000`

`echo ${a:0:-4}:${a#${a:0:-4}}`

Output:

`0x2aab3f43:9000`

Comment: For me this throws: `-4: substring expression < 0`

Answer (score 1):

An other pure bash answer:

```
sh$ V=0x2aab3f439000
sh$ echo ${V::(-4)}:${V:(-4)}
0x2aab3f43:9000
```

Comment: For me this throws: `line 11: (-4): substring expression < 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
RESULT="$( \
    echo -n $ORIG | head -c $(( $(echo -n "$ORIG" | wc -c) - 4)) && \
    echo -n : && \
    echo -n $ORIG | tail -c 4 \
)"
```

Proof of concept:

```
me@ ~$ ORIG="hello world"
me@ ~$ RESULT="$( \
>     echo -n $ORIG | head -c $(( $(echo -n "$ORIG" | wc -c) - 4)) && \
>     echo -n : && \
>     echo -n $ORIG | tail -c 4 \
> )"
me@ ~$ echo "$RESULT"
hello w:orld
```

There are certainly more elegant ways of doing this, but it's hard to beat this for clarity.

Comment: sorry man, but calling 3 external programs (head, wc, tail) 4x forking a subshell is not a very effective way... ;)

Comment: @jm666 "Effective" is a relative term. It was the first way that occurred to me. Thinking of another way would take more time than would be saved. If I wanted to conserve resources, I wouldn't be using bash in the first place. And if I only need to add a colon once in the script, the self-evident nature of this code (to me, anyway) would be better than wasting time looking up sed or awk documentation every time I look over the source.

Comment: @jm666 Otherwise, I agree with you. If you're going through a file and need to perform this operation 10,000 times, my solution would not be a good one. Although it'd certainly be cache-friendly; `wc`, `head`, and `tail` are all small programs.

Comment: TL;DR? Mine was one of the first answers, and it was just a quick fix to the problem as stated. Disregarding worst-case scalability (which any bash question implicitly does, anyway), this solution is morally equivalent to all of the others. If you care about scalability, use C with pthreads.

Comment: Man, don't take things personally, but professionally. Adding a colon to an string is trivial, see other answers. Even if you answer is really not effective, I'm not down-voted it. ;) You can learn many news things here - simple by study others answers - youre in a good way. ;)

Comment: @jm666 I didn't take it personally; I just know that, professionally, there's no reason to waste bandwidth getting good at doing string processing in bash scripts. You should never be doing a lot of string processing in bash. Bash is a glue language. If you need more than basic PoC code or application bootstrapping, use a real industrial-strength language like perl, python, C or ruby. That having been said, now I know the other solutions, I won't use the one I gave.

Comment: @jm666 ...I'm just kinda talkative and like to argue. Your point's a good one; just thought the counterpoint was worth expressing.